# Stop inertia scroll of MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, mkmapview

Here is the problem: I have my `MKMapView` with `scrollEnabled=YES` and `zoomEnabled=YES`, I have a button that sets some certain region to the map and sets `scrollEnabled=NO` and `zoomEnabled=NO`.

Everything works fine when I simply tap that button. But if I scroll my map a bit so it starts to scroll further 'cause of inertia and tap my button while map continues to scroll I get stuck in the region my map scrolled to during inertia scrolling.

Here's some code if it helps:

```
- (void)openMap
{
    MKMapView * mapView = self.contentView.locationView.mapView;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)closeMap
{
    MKMapView * mapView = self.contentView.locationView.mapView;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {self.event.eventLocation.latitude.floatValue, self.event.eventLocation.longitude.floatValue};
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);
}
```

So what I want is to be able to instantly stop that inertia scroll of MKMapView when I press my button.

Comment: I can not reproduce this bug, could you clarify the following questions:
1. You test on device or simulator?
2. iOS version

Comment: @Numeral, I test on device with iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a bug at MKMapView implementation. The only solution that i have is to recreate map in closeMap method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[self addMap];
}

- (void)addMap {

self.map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.map];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.map];
}


- (void)recreateMap {

[self.map removeFromSuperview];
self.map = nil;
[self addMap];
}


- (void)openMap
{
MKMapView * mapView = self.map;
mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
}


- (void)closeMap {

[self recreateMap];
MKMapView * mapView = self.map;
mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {self.event.eventLocation.latitude.floatValue, self.event.eventLocation.longitude.floatValue};
mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);
}
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I do some scale animation of my map on closeMap and openMap. I'll try to use this method and see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be not a good solution for me. I'd like to make something less brute. Still would really like to instantly stop the inertia scrolling.

Comment: I tried different solutions and concluded that this bug may be caused by map loading events (not by map view deceleration). Hope this helps.